# How to read excel file in angular with typography?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, xlsx

I want to read data from excel sheet with  typography. Currently , I am using xlsx npm library to  read data. It help us to get data in plain JSON format.
For example, if a user added a text in cell like this =>

1. List item 1
2. List item 2
3. List item 3
4. List item 4
   then I will be able to get this list with same typography in stringify HTML format so that user can view data in browser with same typography as he/she entered in excel sheet.
   Can someone help me with this?
   Thanks.

Comment: Yes we can help you, but you need to ask more specific questions. This question basically means 'can you do it for me?'. We're eager to help you doing it yourself. Paste some of your code, where do you run stuck, how can we help?